# dictionary of lists in c#(cant seem to get my lists)

Tags: c#, linq, list, collections

Here i used linq to filter my result in an array and pass into a list and from that list into a dictionary as you can see below

```
//array is a multidimensional array with string data in it 
var datumn = array;
var list = new List<string>();
var stringcounts = new Dictionary<int,List<string>>();
var listtemp = new List<string>();

//linq

var arrayresult = from string a in datumn where a != "FREE" select a;

//adding result from arrayresult to list

foreach (var listing in arrayresult)
{
    list.Add(listing);
}

//using linq again i filter my list then add to dictionary

for (int count = 3; count > 0; count-- )
{
    var duplicateItems = from x in list
                         group x by x into grouped
                         where grouped.Count() == count 
                         select grouped.Key;
    foreach (var replace in duplicateItems)
    {
        listtemp.Add(replace.ToString());
    }

    stringcounts.Add(count, lists);

    //clearing the list to avoid duplicating data in my dictionary 
    listtemp.Clear();

}

for (int key = stringcounts.Count; key > 0; --key)
{
    var holding = stringcounts[key];

    foreach (var li in holding)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(li.ToString());
        //just view what i have to check if the data is correct
    }

}
```

`
the program skips iterator over of the lists and ends can some one help with this 
and i have tried everything including linq and other collections like hashtable
and maps but nothing works and it is not a console application

Comment: I don't have a clue what is the problem. I'm not an english native speaker myself, but I know that you should phrase your question in a way that anyone would understand.

Comment: @KamilT take a look at it now if you can spot my error cause i cant :?

Comment: @Carra take a look at it above(the whole code i tried to shorten)

Answer (score 7):

This line is wrong:

```
   var dict = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>();
```

Remove the ";".

Result:

> indigo silver violet purple green pink red brown yellow

Edit: full code for comparison:

```
   var dict = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>()
  {
 {1, new List<string>{"red", "brown", "yellow"}},
 {2, new List<string>{"purple", "green", "pink"}},
 {3, new List<string>{"indigo", "silver", "violet"}}        
  };

// now i want to get my values from the lists in the dictionary 

for (int count = 3; count > 0; count--)
{
    var l = dict[count];

    foreach (var li in l)
    {
        li.Dump();
    }
}
```

Comment: still not working :? ryt naw the program reads the key values cause i just did a check on it but the values itself i.e the list do not show up on display

Comment: I have tested it with linqpad, replaced the Message.Show by a Dump(). It should work;

Comment: @Carra i think i should post my whole code so u see whats wrong with it cause its been days

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (var item in dict)
        {
            var list = item.Value;
            foreach (var str in list)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(str);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The listtemp.Clear() is a bad syntax so therefore it should be removed and the listtemp should be declared in the for loop therefore removing redundancy and the initial problem